# Error when trying to println an NSString from NSDictionary (JSON)

Tags: json, swift, nsstring, nsdictionary

There is something that I can't understand... I have this function :

```
func getDataByKey(key: String, jsonDict: NSDictionary) -> NSString {
    for (name, value) in jsonDict {
        if name.isEqual(key) {
            println(value)
            return value as NSString
        }
    }
    return "-1"
}
```

I get the result in another function, when it returns "-1" I can display it, the println also display the result well but when I try to display the value returned on the line "return value as NSString" my app shutdown with (lldb).

Any idea of where it could come from ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because you force the cast to NSString with `!`, it will crash when the value corresponding to the key is not an NSString, and also when the value is `nil`.

[image]

You probably should do a safety check first. More important: is there a particular reason why you would re-invent how to access to a dictionary?

This is the normal way of getting an NSString value from a key:

```
let result = myDictionary["key"] as! NSString
```

And if you're not sure if the dictionary contents is an NSString:

```
if let result = myDictionary["key"] as? NSString {
    println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a variable can ever be nil you must tell your program that it can have an expected value of nil. This is done with the ? operator. The ! operator implies that it will always have a value of the expected type. Yours is hitting a value that is not an NSString.

You can amend this by doing the following to your code:

```
func getDataByKey(key: String, jsonDict: NSDictionary) -> NSString {
    for (name, value) in jsonDict {
        if name.isEqual(key) {
            println(value)
            if let unwrappedResult = value as? NSString {
                return unwrappedResult
            }
        }
    }
    return "-1"
}
```